# How to cleanup "Library/Containers/com.docker.docker" on a Mac?

Tags: docker

I have an MacBook Air (10.14.6) and the folder `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/` contains 64 GB of data!!

How to clean up this folder?

Comment: Are you sure it actually contains that much? Containers include aliases to other folders, and some disk management software can count the contents of the alias. You can of course just delete it all (after all, you have a backup).

Comment: I have a backup?

Comment: If you don't have a backup now, you will after a data loss...

Comment: @Alex Files without a backup are waiting to be lost. This site is full of "how do I get my files back?" questions.

Comment: If I dont have Docker on my machine anymore, can I delete this folder?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt the folder is 64 GB. That’s a very round number, the sort one might select as the disk size in Docker Desktop preferences.

Given 64 GB is set as the maximum size of the disk, Finder will show the size as this. Get Info and check the size on disk instead.

[image: Docker Get Info in Finder showing size on disk]

To get a breakdown and accurate sizes, run `docker system df`.

Docker can cope with files being deleted in this folder as long as it’s not running, but data will be lost. However the more standard way to free space is to `docker system prune`. See `--help` for usage.

For more information about how Docker Desktop stores data on disk, see https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/space/.

Comment: The size of the folder is indeed 64.01 GB. `docker system df` yields: `TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              2                   2                   403.4MB             0B (0%)
Containers          2                   2                   63B                 0B (0%)
Local Volumes       1                   1                   41.98MB             0B (0%)
Build Cache         0                   0                   0B                  0B`

Comment: @Alex How are you determining the folder is 64 GB? That command hasn’t returned anywhere near 64 GB!

Comment: Oh, it seems `Finder` has a bug. It shows the folder to have 64GB, but `df -d 1 -m ` shows it to have less than 3GB. Looks like I cannot trust `Finder`...

Comment: @Alex It’s not a bug, as discussed above it’s the maximum size of the disk. Finder’s Get Info does report the ‘size on disk’ too which is accurate.

Comment: So Finder does not tell me the used size within a folder?

Comment: @Alex As above, Get Info and check the size on disk. I’ve added a screenshot too now.